# How to use js-year-calendar with Angular8

Tags: angular, migration

I want to migrate from `bootstrap-year-calendar` to `js-year-calendar` because `bootstrap-year-calendar` is deprecated.

Has anybody a working example for this case ?

Comment: Try [Year calendar](https://year-calendar.github.io/rc-year-calendar/examples)

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with fullCalendar, which is a different product. Please check each tag's description before adding the tag. If you tag your questions accurately, they are much more likely to be seen by people with relevant expertise, and much less likely to needlessly take up time of people who are not interested in it. I have removed irrelevant the tag for you on this occasion, thanks.

Comment: I build an [example](https://github.com/dosencode/yearcalendar-demo)